# What protocol does TeamViewer use?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, teamviewer, protocol, network-protocols

I was just teaching someone a little about SSH & VNC. I said I'd show him some things with TeamViewer. Then he asked me "Soo.. is this a VNC client?
And I wasn't sure.

What protocol does TeamViewer use? It's obviously similar to VNC & RDP and so on. However, I can't seem to find much information on it.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com duplicate: [How Team Viewer establish Remote Desktop Connection](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/14280)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TeamViewer uses its own proprietary protocol. It is not documented, though its authentication layer has been partially analyzed:

- [http://www.ixiacom.com/about-us/news-events/corporate-blog/magic-teamviewer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160417015729/http://www.ixiacom.com/about-us/news-events/corporate-blog/magic-teamviewer)
- [http://www.accuvant.com/blog/teamviewer-authentication-protocol-part-1-of-3](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306132655/http://www.accuvant.com/blog/teamviewer-authentication-protocol-part-1-of-3)

It is similar to RDP or VNC (RFB) in purpose, but includes NAT traversal, has slightly different authentication methods (the one-time PINs), supports file transfer & chat, and adapts to network conditions dynamically.

Comment: The NAT traversal must be possible because it is not peer-to-peer, as there is a server to establish connection, unlike RDP and VNC.

Comment: It's mostly peer-to-peer. Quite a few protocols (e.g. pre-MS Skype) only use central nodes purely for NAT hole punching, not for data relaying.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the NAT traversal / hole punching part?